# Redirect Dynamic URL with one parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a url as mydomain.com/store.php?id=3.

I would like to convert(redirect) to static URL on the base of id.
Replace the ID with the store name (from database) and add some hard coated keyword at the end of url.
URL should be look like this one mydomain.com/storename-keyword1-keyword2.html

Please guide me that what is the best way to do this? I have used a lot of my time to handle this issue but no result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this? [How can I make my urls friendly from this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974421/how-can-i-make-my-urls-friendly-from-this-example)

That is, you are still serving the content using the script `store.php` but you want the browser's location bar to have a clean URL that looks like `/storename/word/word.html`? You're obviously going to need to change some of the rewrite matches and targets to suit the URLs that you want. Something like?

```
RewriteRule ^storename-([^\-]+)-(.+).html /store.php?id=$1&something=$2&rewritten=true [L]
```